# Is there a way to get results of solr grouping using Solr Net

Tags: solrnet

I want to try new solr collapsing/grouping included in solr 3.3, i have tried queries on solr Admin page and that works absolutely right but when I try to query in my c# code using solr net that does not seem to work as expected. Here is how I am setting the param values

```
    options.ExtraParams = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
    {
        new KeyValuePair<string,string>("group","true"),
        new KeyValuePair<string,string>("group.field","AuthorID"),
    };
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use Grouping (formerly known as Field Collapsing) with SolrNet, it was introduced in the SolrNet 0.4.0 alpha1 release. Here are the [release notes](http://bugsquash.blogspot.com/2011/06/solrnet-040-alpha-1-released.html) on the author's blog about this support being added in. So you will need to grab that version (or later) from [Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/downloads/list)(binaries) or [GitHub](https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet)(source). Also here is an example of using grouping from the unit tests in the source - [Grouping Tests](https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/blob/2321d4d2522b4c0f14414f2cf21569ffc032e36d/SolrNet.Tests/Integration.Sample/Tests.cs#L464)

```
public void FieldGrouping()
{
    var solr = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ISolrBasicOperations<Product>>();
    var results = solr.Query(SolrQuery.All, new QueryOptions
    {
        Grouping = new GroupingParameters()
        {
            Fields = new [] { "manu_exact" },
            Format = GroupingFormat.Grouped,
            Limit = 1,
        }
    });

    Console.WriteLine("Group.Count {0}", results.Grouping.Count);
    Assert.AreEqual(1, results.Grouping.Count);
    Assert.AreEqual(true, results.Grouping.ContainsKey("manu_exact"));
    Assert.GreaterThanOrEqualTo(results.Grouping["manu_exact"].Groups.Count,1);
}
```